# Does aws config pricing model include the number of api requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

I use the configService (AWS Config API) to retrieve the history of configurations of all resources recorded by the aws config service.
I use exactly these two endpoints :

- listDiscoveredResources
- getResourceConfigHistory

Since there are multiple resources recorded by the aws config, I want to know the cost of a large number of api calls for the two functionalities above.

I looked up the aws config pricing model, but it doesn't seem to inlcude api request, it only prices by:

- Configurations items recorded
- config rules evaluated
- conformance packs

Is there anyway to get the cost for a number of api request to the aws config api.